# Scrape App metrics using Prometheus with Envoy side car proxy

Tags: prometheus, istio, telemetry, istio-sidecar, istio-prometheus

I am using GKE for my workloads. I have installed Istio 1.11.0 on my cluster. I have also have installed Prometheus in `istio-system` namespace using this [link](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/).

I have a Python application deployed in the `prom-test` namespace, which is collecting metrics at port 8080 as below.

[image: app metrics]

I have used the below annotation in the deployment file to have the metrics **scraped** by Prometheus

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
    prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    prometheus.io/scheme: http
    prometheus.io/path: "/metrics"
```

There are 2 containers running in the 1) the application container and 2) the envoy proxy container

[image]

When I bring up the Prometheus dashboard, I see all Targets are up and for my app its being **scraped** at

[image]

But I could see any application related metrics?

[image]

It would be really helpful, if veterans here can advise on the same

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. It seems for. Python i need to add the info as a scrape config in `prommetheus.yaml` file. Once I have implemented the same, it started working.

Able to see the metrics on Istio prometheus.